# i Cannot be resolved as variable (Processing)

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to create array list for triangular grid on Processing and it keeps saying that 
'Unexpected token: [' on the first line and also for `intPrevX=[ ]`

Is this not the correct form to write an array?  This was the same line being used in the reference code and it seems to not work on mine. Not sure how to rewrite this..

the second problem is, it says that for line 42:     `for (i = 0; i < 20; i++){`
it says i cannot be resolved to a variable and I am not sure what this error message means. Sounds like I've passed down the variable in a wrong way..

```
int x =[], y = [];
int prevX =[], prevY = [];

Boolean fade = true;

void setup()
{
    size( 450, 400 );
    background( 0 );
    stroke( 255 );

    x[0] = width/2;
    y[0] = height/2;

    prevX[0] = x[0];
    prevY[0] = y[0];

    prevX[1] = x[0];
    prevY[1] = y[0];

    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight( 2 );
    point( x[0], y[0] );
    scale(.01);

}

void draw()
{
    if (fade) {
     //   background(0);
        noStroke();
        fill( 0, 4 );
        rect( 0, 0, width, height );
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    float angle = (TWO_PI / 6) * floor( random( 6 ));
    x[i+1] = x[i] + cos( angle ) * radius;
    y[i+1] = y[i] + sin( angle ) * radius;

    if ( x[i+1] < 0 || x[i+1] > width || x[i] > width) {
        x[i+1] = prevX[i];
        y[i+1] = prevY[i];
    }

    if ( y[i+1] < 0 || y[i+1] > height|| y[i] > height) {
        x[i+1] = prevX[i];
        y[i+1] = prevY[i];
    }

    stroke( 255, 64 );
    strokeWeight( 1 );
    line( x[i+1], y[i+1], prevX[i], prevY[i] );

    strokeWeight( 3 );
    point( x[i+1], y[i+1] );

    prevX[i+1] = x[i+1];
    prevY[i+1] = y[i+1];

     if (x[i+1] == x[i-2] && y[i+1] == y[i-2]) {
    fill(255);
    beginShape();

    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
      vertex(x[i+j-2], y[i+j-2]);
    }
    endShape(CLOSE);


    }


   /* if(i >=1){
      prevX[0] = x[i+1];
      prevY[0] = x[i+1];

      angle = (TWO_PI / 6) * floor( random( 6 ));
      x[0] = x[i+1] + cos( angle ) * radius;
      y[0] = y[i+1] + sin( angle ) * radius;

      line( x[0], y[0], x[i+1], y[i+1] );
    }*/
    }

}

void keyPressed()
{
    if (key == 'f') {
        fade = !fade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to declare an array in Java is

```
int[] x;   
int[] y = new int[size]; // if you already know the array size
```

and so on.

Check this for details on how to use arrays in Java: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-in-java/

Comment: Thanks Luca for the link!